# How do I call methods on other elements?

Tags: javascript, polymer

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="my-thing">
    <script>
        Polymer('my-thing', {
            athing: function () { return 'hello' }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I want the use the element defined above in the element below and have access to the athing property.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./mything.html">


<polymer-element name="my-hello"">
    <template>
         <my-thing id="mything"></my-thing>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-hello', {
            ready: function () {
                this.$.mything.athing() // returns undefined
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes with id's are reflected in the `$` hash, not in `this`, so

`this.$.mything.athing(); // returns 'hello'`

[Poster changed his example to include the missing `.$`]

After fixing the syntax, I cannot recreate your problem.

http://jsbin.com/tegefura/1/edit

Comment: Thanks so much! That was actually a typo.

Comment: I'm confused, now your example says: `this.$.mything.athing() // returns undefined` ... is that still what you observe?

Comment: Yes, I changed my example, previously I left out the "$", which was a typo. The example above is what I am observing.